# Load multiple-martrix file into Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a file that contains multiple numerical matrices. All matrices are separated  by newline as shown in the example below:

0,-1,18 
1,2,1
2,-1,7
3,-1,12
4,-1,7

5,-1,23
6,-1,18
7,-1,10 
5,-1,23
8,2,9
9,2,8

15,-1,1
128,-1,7
174,-1,8
175,-1,0
176,-1,7

I wanna load this file into Matlab workspace so that each matrix will be assigned to a different variable.

Matlab provides a simple load function that apparently doesn't work for such kind of format.

It would be very useful if you have any clue of how load such file.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code below reads all the lines with TEXTSCAN, splits them to separate matrices by empty lines, then converts to double.

As a result you get cell array `out` with double matrices as individual cells. For example to access the 1st matrix use `out{1}`, etc. It's better than individual variables.

```
%# open file and read all lines
fid = fopen('test6.txt','rt');
temp = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
temp = [temp{:}];
fclose(fid);

%# find empty lines
idxSep = find(cellfun(@isempty, temp));
%# separate matrices to different cells
temp2 = mat2cell(temp, diff([0; idxSep; numel(temp)]), 1);
%# remove empty lines
temp2(1:end-1) = cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-1), temp2(1:end-1), 'UniformOutput',0);

%# convert cell arrays to double
out = cell(size(temp2));
for k = 1:numel(temp2)
    out{k} = cellfun(@str2num, temp2{k}, 'UniformOutput',0);
end
out = cellfun(@cell2mat, out, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

I probably missed something to make the code simpler. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So import the file into one matrix and split it into the sub-matrices you want.  `uiimport` or `dlmread` will do the first part of this, you'll have to do the second part.

If your dataset is so large that you can't load it all at once and copy it into other variables, then you'll have to experiment with `textscan` or similar functions to read the file in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

I changed the file to the following format:

n=3     %number of matrices

r=3 %number of raws in the current matrix
0 -1 18
1 2 1
2 -1 7


r=3
3 -1 12
4 -1 7
5 -1 23


r=5
6 -1 18
7 -1 10
5 -1 23
8 2 9
9 2 8


And I implemented the following simple function

```
function data = load_sparse_data(filename)

% open the file
fid = fopen(filename);
% find N (The total number of matrices)
N = fscanf(fid, 'n=%d\n', 1);

% read each matrix
for n = 1:N
    % skip line
    fscanf(fid, '\n', 1);

    % find R, the number of raws
    R = fscanf(fid, 'r=%d\n', 1);

    % fscanf fills the array in column order,
    % so transpose the results
    data(n).mat  = ...
    fscanf(fid, '%f', [3, R])';

    % skip line
    fscanf(fid, '\n', 1);
end 

%cloes the file
fclose(fid);
```